# Launch Screen Image is Not Appearing in SwiftUI App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, launchimage

I'm developing my first iOS app and am having issues with the launch screen. Using the /iOS/Info.plist file I've added my launch image, which is set up in the Assets library, and its associated values in the library, but the image will not show up in the simulator or on my iPhone. I have tried clearing out the Xcode derived data folder to clear out the cached launch information as was recommended online and this did not help. Below are screenshots of my setup, and I would appreciate any ideas or help!

Info.plist:
[image: Info.plist]

Asset Library:
[image: Asset Library]

Comment: Would you please reinstall the app again?

Comment: I reinstalled on both my phone and an iOS 11 simulator, still nothing on the launch screen.

Answer (score 1):

Change your iOS Deployment Target to iOS 13. SwiftUI requires iOS 13+

Comment: or  **UPDATE** your device's iOS version.